# Error when getBlock('category.products.list') in Observer

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, category, event-observer, category-products

```
    public function __construct(
        Config $pageConfig,
        Category $categoryHelper,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ){
        $this->pageConfig = $pageConfig;
        $this->categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    } 

   
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        if ('catalog_category_view' != $observer->getEvent()->getFullActionName()) {
            return $this;
        }
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $productListBlock */
        $productListBlock = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getBlock('category.products.list');
        $category = $productListBlock->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory();
        
        /**
         * Remove default canonical tag
         */
        if ($this->categoryHelper->canUseCanonicalTag()) {
            $this->pageConfig->getAssetCollection()->remove($category->getUrl());
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $toolbarBlock */
        $toolbarBlock = $productListBlock->getToolbarBlock();
        /** @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager $pagerBlock */
        $pagerBlock = $toolbarBlock->getChildBlock('product_list_toolbar_pager');
        $pagerBlock->setAvailableLimit($toolbarBlock->getAvailableLimit())
            ->setCollection($productListBlock->getLayer()->getProductCollection());
        
        /**
         * Add rel canonical with page variable
         */
        $this->pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
            $this->getPageUrl([
                $pagerBlock->getPageVarName() => $pagerBlock->getCurrentPage()
            ]),
            'canonical',
            ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'canonical']]
        );

        /**
         * Add rel prev and rel next
         */
        if (1 < $pagerBlock->getCurrentPage()) {
            $this->pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
                $this->getPageUrl([
                    $pagerBlock->getPageVarName() => $pagerBlock->getCollection()->getCurPage(-1)
                ]),
                'link_rel',
                ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'prev']]
            );
        }
        if ($pagerBlock->getCurrentPage() < $pagerBlock->getLastPageNum()) {
            $this->pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
                $this->getPageUrl([
                    $pagerBlock->getPageVarName() => $pagerBlock->getCollection()->getCurPage(+1)
                ]),
                'link_rel',
                ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'next']]
            );
        }

        return $this;
    }
    protected function getPageUrl($params = [])
    {
        $urlParams = [];
        $urlParams['_current'] = false;
        $urlParams['_escape'] = true;
        $urlParams['_use_rewrite'] = true;
        $urlParams['_query'] = $params;
    
        return $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('*/*/*', $urlParams);
    }
```

Error:

```
2020/08/06 15:15:17 [error] 1352#1352: *500 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getLayer() on bool in /var/www/html/CDE/app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/Observer/CategoryLinks.php:53
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code to change

**From:**

```
$productListBlock = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getBlock('category.products.list');
```

**To:**

```
$controller   = $observer->getAction();
$productListBlock = $controller->getLayout()->getBlock('category.products.list');
```