# Call to a member function getLayer() on boolean in observer magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

I get the error "Call to a member function getLayer() on boolean in app/code/WebSite/ProductListing/Observer/AddCategoryPager.php:40" On magento 2.2.11

I would like to get my block in my observer.

The Observer

```
<?php
namespace WebSite\ProductListing\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddCategoryPager implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $categoryHelper;
    protected $pageConfig;
    protected $urlBuilder;
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $pageConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry

    ) {
        $this->categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        $this->pageConfig = $pageConfig;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * Event layout_generate_blocks_after
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        if ('catalog_category_view' != $observer->getEvent()->getFullActionName()) {
            return $this;
        }
        if(!$this->displayPager()) {
            return $this;
        }
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $productListBlock */
        $productListBlock = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getBlock('category.products.list');
        $category = $productListBlock->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory();

        /**
         * Remove default canonical tag
         */
        if ($this->categoryHelper->canUseCanonicalTag()) {
            $this->pageConfig->getAssetCollection()->remove($category->getUrl());
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $toolbarBlock */
        $toolbarBlock = $productListBlock->getToolbarBlock();
        /** @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager $pagerBlock */
        $pagerBlock = $toolbarBlock->getChildBlock('product_list_toolbar_pager');
        $pagerBlock->setAvailableLimit($toolbarBlock->getAvailableLimit())
            ->setCollection($productListBlock->getLayer()->getProductCollection());

        /**
         * Add rel canonical with page var
         */
        if (1 < $pagerBlock->getCurrentPage()) {
            $this->pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
                $this->getPageUrl([
                    $pagerBlock->getPageVarName() => $pagerBlock->getCurrentPage()
                ]),
                'canonical',
                ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'canonical']]
            );
        } else {
            $this->pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
                $this->getPageUrl([]),
                'canonical',
                ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'canonical']]
            );
        }

        /**
         * Add rel prev and rel next
         */
        if (1 < $pagerBlock->getCurrentPage()) {
            $this->pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
                $this->getPageUrl([
                    $pagerBlock->getPageVarName() => $pagerBlock->getCollection()->getCurPage(-1)
                ]),
                'link_rel',
                ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'prev']]
            );
        }
        if ($pagerBlock->getCurrentPage() < $pagerBlock->getLastPageNum()) {
            $this->pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
                $this->getPageUrl([
                    $pagerBlock->getPageVarName() => $pagerBlock->getCollection()->getCurPage(+1)
                ]),
                'link_rel',
                ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'next']]
            );
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function displayPager() {
        $displayFilterAsLink = false;
        $currentCategory = $this->getCurrentCategory();
        $isPageproducer = $this->getIsPageProducer();
        $categoryLevel = $currentCategory->getLevel();
        $arrCategoryToDisplayPagerAsLink = [
            1199, // Primeur
            1198  // Bordeaux Primeur
        ];

        if($categoryLevel == 5 || $isPageproducer || in_array($currentCategory->getId(), $arrCategoryToDisplayPagerAsLink)) {
            $displayFilterAsLink = true;
        }


        return $displayFilterAsLink;
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory() {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }
    public function getIsPageProducer() {
        $producer = $this->_registry->registry('current_blog_post');
        if(!empty($producer)) {
            $return = true;
        } else {
            $return = false;
        }
        return $return;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve page URL by defined parameters
     *
     * @param array $params
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getPageUrl($params = [])
    {
        $urlParams = [];
        $urlParams['_current'] = false;
        $urlParams['_escape'] = true;
        $urlParams['_use_rewrite'] = true;
        $urlParams['_query'] = $params;

        return $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('*/*/*', $urlParams);
    }
}
```

The catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2colmuns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true" />

        <move element="page.main.title" destination="category.view.container" before="category.description"/>


        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="WebSite\OpenGraph\Block\ImageTag" name="opengraph_image" template="WebSite_ProductListing::opengraph/tag.phtml" after="-" />
        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list" class="WebSite\ProductListing\Block\Product\ListProduct"
                        template="WebSite_ProductListing::product/list.phtml" >
            <referenceBlock class="WebSite\ProductListing\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar"
                            template="WebSite_ProductListing::product/list/toolbar.phtml" >

                <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar_pager" class="WebSite\ProductListing\Block\Html\Pager"
                            template="WebSite_ProductListing::product/list/pager.phtml" />
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceBlock>

    </body>
</page>
```

The ListProduct.php block

```
<?php
namespace WebSite\ProductListing\Block\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Api as CatalogApi;
use Magento\Catalog\Model as CatalogModel;

/**
 * Product list
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    /**
     * @var \WebSite\Catalog\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $_catalogHelper;
    protected $_response;
    protected $_productRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteriaBuilder;
    protected $_productAttributeRepository;


    /**
     * ListProduct constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper
     * @param CatalogModel\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
     * @param CatalogApi\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper
     * @param \WebSite\Catalog\Helper\Data $catalogHelper
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        CatalogApi\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
        \WebSite\Catalog\Helper\Data $catalogHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response,
        CatalogApi\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $productAttributeRepository,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $postDataHelper,
            $layerResolver,
            $categoryRepository,
            $urlHelper,
            $data
        );
        $this->_catalogHelper = $catalogHelper;
        $this->_response = $response;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->_productAttributeRepository = $productAttributeRepository;

    }

    /**
     * Retrieve list toolbar HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getToolbarCondHtml($_attribute)
    {
        return $this->getChildBlock('toolbar')->setData("bottom",$_attribute)->_toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
     */
    public function getCategory() {
        return $this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory();
    }

    /**
     * @param CatalogApi\Data\ProductInterface|CatalogModel\Product $product
     * @return string
     */
    public function isVariationDisplayed($product)
    {
        return $this->_catalogHelper->isVariationDisplayed($product);
    }

    /**
     * @param CatalogApi\Data\ProductInterface $product
     * @param array $vintages
     * @return array
     */
    public function getVintagePrices($product, $vintages)
    {
        return $this->_catalogHelper->getVintagePrices($product, $vintages);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magefan\Blog\Model\Post || false
     */
    public function getCurrentBlogProducer() {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry("current_blog_post");
    }


    public function showNote($note){
        if(!empty($note)){
            $ratingLow = explode("-",$note)[0];
            if($ratingLow > 87 || $ratingLow <= 20){ // M2C1895
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
        $productCollection = $this->_getProductCollection();
        $currentBlogProducer = $this->getCurrentBlogProducer();
        if($currentBlogProducer != null){
            if(count($productCollection) == 0) {
                $filterOptionId = $this->getProducerOptionIdByLabel($currentBlogProducer->getTitle());

                $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder
                    ->addFilter(CatalogApi\Data\ProductInterface::STATUS, CatalogModel\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                    ->addFilter(\WebSite\Catalog\Helper\Data::PRODUCT_STOCK_DISPLAY, \WebSite\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\OptionCvStockDisplay::PRODUCT_STOCK_DISPLAY_IN_CUSTOMER_CELLAR, 'gteq')
                    ->addFilter(\WebSite\Catalog\Helper\Data::PRODUCT_STOCK_DISPLAY, \WebSite\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\OptionCvStockDisplay::PRODUCT_STOCK_DISPLAY_IN_CUSTOMER_CELLAR_ALLOW_PROPOSAL,'lteq')
                    ->addFilter(CatalogApi\Data\ProductInterface::TYPE_ID, \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE)
                    ->addFilter("cv_producer", $filterOptionId)
                ;

                $countProductCollectionInCustomerCellar = $this->_productRepository
                    ->getList($this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->create())->getTotalCount();

                $this->_response->setNoCacheHeaders();
                if($countProductCollectionInCustomerCellar == 0) {
                    $this->_response->setRedirect($this->getCategory()->getUrl() , 301)->sendResponse();
                } else {
                    $this->_response->setRedirect($this->getCategory()->getUrl() , 302)->sendResponse();
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->_getProductCollection();
    }

    protected function getProducerOptionIdByLabel($producerLabel) {
        $filterOptionId = null;
        $cvProducerOptions = $this->_productAttributeRepository->get('cv_producer')->getOptions();
        foreach ($cvProducerOptions as $cvProducerOption){
            if($cvProducerOption->getLabel() == $producerLabel){
                $filterOptionId = $cvProducerOption->getValue();
                break;
            }
        }
        return $filterOptionId;
    }

}
```

Event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event [...]
   </event>
   <event name="layout_generate_blocks_after">
      <observer name="add_pager_info_head" instance="Cavissima\ProductListing\Observer\AddCategoryPager" />
   </event>
</config>
```

Comment: what event are you observing?

Comment: I observe "layout_generate_blocks_after"

Comment: check this link :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/319264/85907

Comment: with this solution I have an error on getLayout()  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getLayout() on null in app/code/WebSite/ProductListing/Observer/AddCategoryPager.php:40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I find my error in catalog_category_view.xml

I make an error line 2 :

`layout="2colmuns-left"`

replace by

`layout="2columns-left"`

And it's work.